# Static Route Still Uses Wrong Gateway

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ip-routing

I have 2 servers connected to our corporate lan (10.0.0.0\24) and also connected to a seperate lan (192.168.1.0\30). I am unable to ping one server from the other on the 192.168.1.0 network and doing a tracert shows the first hop to be 10.0.0.226. The following is our current routing table. The route is there. Am I missing something?

```
Ethernet adapter Migration:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.252
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Microsoft Network Adapter Multiplexor Driver -     Virtu
al Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.2
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.226

Tunnel adapter isatap.{C8FB357B-225E-4F71-84A1-0B455B78D021}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{E1F1126B-0ED7-4DF3-BDD6-82DA53340448}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :


 ===========================================================================
 Interface List
  45...a0 36 9f 6d 0d e0 ......Microsoft Network Adapter Multiplexor Driver #2
  21...70 e2 84 06 d6 e9 ......Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
   1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
  14...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
  48...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
 ===========================================================================

 IPv4 Route Table
 ===========================================================================
 Active Routes:
 Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
           0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.0.0.226         10.0.0.1    261
          10.0.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link          10.0.0.1    261
          10.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.1    261
        10.0.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.1    261
         127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
         127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
   127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
       192.168.1.0  255.255.255.252      192.168.1.1         10.0.0.1    261
       192.168.1.0  255.255.255.252         On-link       192.168.1.1    261
       192.168.1.1  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.1    261
       192.168.1.3  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.1    261
         224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
         224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link          10.0.0.1    261
         224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.1.1    261
   255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
   255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.1    261
   255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.1    261
 ===========================================================================
 Persistent Routes:
   Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
           0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.0.0.226  Default
           0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.0.0.226  Default
           0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.0.0.226     256
 ===========================================================================

 IPv6 Route Table
 ===========================================================================
 Active Routes:
  If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
   1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
  45    261 fe80::/64                On-link
  45    261 fe80::9df2:675b:7dac:43d7/128
                                On-link
   1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
  45    261 ff00::/8                 On-link
 ===========================================================================
 Persistent Routes:
   None
```

Other system

```
Ethernet adapter Migration:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 192.168.1.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.252
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Microsoft Network Adapter Multiplexor Driver - Virtual Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.226

Tunnel adapter isatap.{C6D18C23-8682-48F7-91CA-29CBA7926666}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{B2032040-F6AE-467E-911C-9F72C77B0B51}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :



===========================================================================
Interface List
 24...78 2b cb 0a 63 67 ......Microsoft Network Adapter Multiplexor Driver #2
 23...78 2b cb 0a 63 65 ......Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 16...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 50...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.0.0.226         10.0.0.2    261
         10.0.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link          10.0.0.2    261
         10.0.0.2  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.2    261
       10.0.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.2    261
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.1.0  255.255.255.252         On-link       192.168.1.2      7
      192.168.1.2  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.2    261
      192.168.1.3  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.2    261
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link          10.0.0.2    261
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.1.2    261
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.2    261
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.2    261
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.0.0.226  Default
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.0.0.226     256
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 24    261 fe80::/64                On-link
 24    261 fe80::4d95:7747:bd8f:81f5/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 24    261 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: Post the complete routing table and ipconfig from both servers.

Comment: So both servers are multi-homed and both servers have at least one 10.0.0.0/24 address and one 192.168.1.0/30 address? And therefore the servers are the only two nodes on the 192.168.1.0/30 network? There might be an interface binding order that would make it try the 192 interface first and then if that doesn't work it will go to the 10 interface and then use the default gateway on that interface.

Comment: You are correct about the ip scheme. Any idea as to why on sever would show the corect interface for the network and the other show the incorrect interface? Is there a way to change the interface for the route entry?

Comment: If you can post the entire route print output from the second server that would be helpful. Also posting the ipconfig output from both servers would be helpful. The odd route on server 2 should have no bearing on how server 1 attempts to communicate with server 2.

Comment: I just posted them but inverted the order accidentally.

Comment: I just noticed the 169 address for the "Other system". This is odd as I have it set static in network settings.

Comment: This looks like your problem to me.  the route is using an APIPA address, not the statically configured address.  try deleting the route and re-adding it.

192.168.1.0  255.255.255.252      192.168.1.1   169.254.67.215      7

Comment: I just corrected it and I can ping from .2 to .1 but not vice-versa

Comment: The interface columns in the routing tables list interface ips of the *other* server ??

Answer (score 3):

Looks like when you added the static route you added it on the wrong interface on machine 1. If you don't specify an interface, Windows picks one by itself and I'm not sure what it uses to choose but I've never seen it choose the right one. `route delete 192.168.1.1` should do it.

Secondly, you have an invalid static route on machine 2. Deleting both of these (and using no static routes at all) should work fine.

Comment: Agreed on getting rid of the persistent routes. Those are unnecessary. Delete all of the persistent routes on both servers, reboot both servers and try again.